# Delete Excel Column with specific name via script

Tags: vba, excel

I need to delete a column in different exports (column is always the same) before importing it into a database. I want it to be automatically done when the excel file is saved in a specific folder. Can anyone give advice on how to start and/or do it?

Jo

Comment: Definitely you need to use VBA, so at first add also VBA tag to your question:). As you didn't write whether you know VBA or not I don't know whether you need link to good VBA tutorials, or really some hints on the ways to write the code.

Comment: You're right, i'll add that right away. I have some basic knowledge in VBA, but nothing too crazy. So what i'd need would be how to set up the code correctly. And i could need some help with adding and filling a column, also by script?

Comment: First step probably would be to search for Workbook.BeforeSave, that's the location where you need to add your code. Adding and filling the column can be done through VBA too.

Comment: @MátéJuhász: VBA is not strictly required. You could also automate Excel from a PowerShell script, or write a .NET (or even native) application to implement the modifications. These options can provide a solution, if the operations are part of a larger workflow, or if you cannot deploy the VBA module to every machine where the functionality is required.

Comment: Okay so basically what i need. I get a daily report attached to an e-mail. I already made a script so it saves the attachement automatically in a specific folder. After that, one column from the excel needs to be deleted while another one is created and has the current date in every line. Then the excel should be saved and imported to a database which i manage via Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio.
EDIT: I have a deticated pc which only runs to do this single task. So this is my setup, what would you guys recommend?

Answer (score 0):

-Create a macro to save the file to a specific folder.

-When the macro is called, delete the column before saving `Columns([Column Number]).EntireColumn.Delete`

Check Excel forums for help